# delete duplicate records with "in"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id SERIAL,
  a INTEGER,
  b INTEGER,
  some DOUBLE,
  other VARCHAR,
  data INTEGER
);
```

And I know that `(a, b)` must be unique, but for some reasons, this is not enforced by the database. Suppose I don't care about further discrimination, I just wipe duplicates from time to time, and maybe only keep the most recent one (with the biggest ID):

```sql
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT max(id) FROM foo GROUP BY a, b);
```

Now suppose that there are several 100.000 records, the `IN (...)` becomes pretty large.

I read about self-joins (like: `DELETE FROM foo a LEFT JOIN foo b ON a.a = b.a AND a.b = b.b WHERE b.id < a.id`), but this also means that I get huge intermediate tables if I have many duplicates.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Is there an (a, b) index?

Comment: No, there is not. Still Gordon's answer was super fast compared to the `NOT IN` code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete older duplicate values, you can use:

```
delete from foo
    where foo.id < (select max(foo2.id)
                    from foo foo2
                    where foo2.a = foo.a and foo2.b = foo.b
                   );
```

Note that an index on `(a, b, id)` would help performance.

You can also phrase this as a join:

```
delete from foo
    using (select a, b, max(id) as max_id
           from foo
           group by a, b
          ) ab
    where foo.a = a.a and foo.b = ab.b and foo.id < ab.max_id;
```

Comment: Wow! That was 8 seconds compared to my "after 10 minutes still pending" first try! It's a little bit magical for me (what intermediate table I can imagine for the subquery part), but I think it's nothing but indicated for me to understand the subquery here. Thank you so much!